# replacing fragments causes an overlapping problem with a single framelayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make a app with all the three combination of BottomNavigation, NavigationDrawer and TabLayout. BottomNavigation has three buttons, each button has a separate fragment. NavigationDrawer has 4 menu items and each one has a separate fragments. Similarly TabLayout has a PageViewer with  3 tabs, each tab has a separate fragment.

I have design the requirement but there is a  overlapping problem of all fragments  of all the above mentioned 3 controls. 
And I could not perform the actions like button clicks. If I click on a button action method using OnClick  event, the control is not going to the action method associated to that button.
Also the controls on each fragment is overlapping with another fragment controls and also visible.

I am using only one  framelayout for BottomNavigation and  NavigationDrawer  for a changing the fragments.
How to  solve the overlapping  problem between the fragments.

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent”
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

             <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_paren/>
     <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView/>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="407dp/>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:openDrawer="start">
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java code for  BottomNavigation, NavigationDrawer and TabLayout.

//MainActivity.Java

//fragment changing with framelayout  for  NavigationDrawer fragments

```
frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 navDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        nnavDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
 NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.navevents:
                        setFragment(events);
                       return true;
                    case R.id.navnews:
                        setFragment(news);
                        dl.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

//fragment changing with framelayout  for BottomNavigation fragments
 bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.navhome:
                        setFragment(Json);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navdetails:
                        setFragment(details);
                        return true;
              }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Similarly 3 fragments are changing with view pager for TabLayout.  But all the fragments are using same framelayout.

```
 //fragments are changing with replace() method. 
  private void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentChanges = 
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentChanges.replace(R.id.frameLayout,fragment);
        fragmentChanges.addToBackStack(null);
       fragmentChanges.commit();
    }
```

I have seen lot of other posts about overlapping of fragments problem.
some of them suggested to remove all fragments and add the fragment which has to be displayed. I have tried as in the below code. But it didn't work.

```
private void changeFragment(Fragment fr){
    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainframe);
    fl.removeAllViews();
    FragmentTransaction transaction1 = 
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction1.add(R.id.mainframe, fr);
   transaction1.commit();
}
```

Cant I use one frame layout for BottomNavigation, NavigationDrawer and TabLayout?  Can anyone suggest me how to solve this problem.